# poetry local dependency in develop mode

Tags: python, python-poetry

I'm trying to use poetry in a project that uses local dependencies. Specifically, I have two other poetry projects that are included as git submodules, I've added them to the top level poetry project as path dependencies.

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.8"
pydantic = "^1.9.0"
adp-utils = {path = "../../adp-utils", develop = false}
adp-cfw = {path = "../../adp-cfw", develop = false}
```

If I set my dependencies with develop = false, I can import them in my client code and all works well. However, since I'm making changes to the libraries as I develop the application, any changes to the library require me to bump the library version and run poetry update on the top level project.

When I try to set develop = true, import statements fail on the top level application. The libraries are still installed, and inspection of the site-packages folder on the venv shows that they are there.

Comment: Any solution since you posted that?

Answer (score 7):

I believe I just ran into the same thing and found the solution.  My project is structured:

- TopLevelApp
- TLACustomLib

  - SomeExternalDependency
  - AnotherExternalDependency

Both the TopLevelApp and the TLACustomLib have their `poetry.toml` configurations set to `in-project = true` so that the dependencies are installed into a virtualenv in each respective project (following in the footsteps of [OpenDoor](https://medium.com/opendoor-labs/our-python-monorepo-d34028f2b6fa)).

TopLevelApp `pyproject.toml` has TLACustomLibs as a dependency similar to yours:

```ini
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
...
tlacustomlibs = {path = "../tlacustomlibs", develop = true}
...
```

On `poetry install`, Poetry will go resolve all of the dependencies of `TLACustomLibs` and add them to the `TopLevelApp` `poetry.lock` file - then install the dependencies directly in `TopLevelApp`'s virtualenv so it has access to them.  But subsequent additions of dependencies to the `TLACustomLib` project will *not* be propagated to the `TopLevelApp`.  Even deleting the `.venv` directory and reinstalling dependencies won't fix the problem.

The fix is to, once you've installed the new dependency in `TLACustomLib`, go to the `TopLevelApp` directory and run a `poetry update` so that it has the chance to update the lockfile.  Then it should be aware of the added sub-dependencies and happily install them in its own top-level virtualenv directory.

Comment: I tried your proposal and still don't get the changes I'm making in the libraries. When I change the code in one library, and execute `poetry update`, I get a message saying `No dependencies to install or update`. After playing a bit, I recreated the virtual env with `poetry env remove python` and then any change is being propagated just installing the dependencies again with `poetry install` ‍♂️

Comment: @logoff does deleting your lock file then running "poetry install" again work? I've found that sometimes I've needed to do that as well.

Comment: Deleting the `.lock` file was not enough, i had to `poetry env list` to get the name and `poetry env remove <name>`, then `poetry update` in order for it to work

Looks like there's a bug in poetry where if you add develop=True it doesn't remove the old cache'd package in the environment

Comment: Thank you @Jonathan, I also encountered the same issue. I had to clear the cache and only then this answer solved the problem. I also had other issues with caching, e.g. after updating poetry from 1.5 to 1.6. Only clearing the caches helped here, too. This indeed indicates that there is a bug in the caching of poetry. Here is a handy one-line to clear all cache entries from poetry: `poetry cache list | xargs -I@ poetry cache clear @ --all` (assuming there is no whitespace in the sources names) [I have updated another poetry answer from you to give you credits :D]

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, but decided that poetry behavior is correct:
"any changes to the library require me to bump the library version" is not the problem poetry is trying to save you from version hell.

I sometimes bring the entire package into the main package folder. You can use symlinks to avoid having copies. Or you can treat the package source as the base version and then migrate changes when you are done. You still need to bump the package version.

If I am still doing a lot of development on a package and I am using my project code as the test driver, I try to remember the package needs to have its own test suite. Every problem I find and fix, should be memorialized as a unit test.

Yes you can fiddle around so that poetry does what you want, but I prefer using version numbers as they were intended: to identify different versions. Two versions with same version number and different contents just confuses me (& poetry).

Given two different packages with the same version number, which one do you expect poetry to choose? If the package is in pypi, it isn't practical for poetry to download the package again, just to see if the cached version is different

I am python & poetry newbie, so I am sure there are better ways. Here is what I do
In each package folder, I leave something like this at the top of each package source tree. I customize each one to build any dependencies.:

poetry_build_this_package.cmd:

```
pushd "%~dp0"

Rem add or more dependencies here
call ..\some_dependency_folder\poetry_build_this_package.cmd

call poetry_build_package.cmd
popd
```

poetry_build_package.cmd, must be somewhere on your PATH:

```
REM building in %CD%
poetry update

@echo. ##### Requirements for packages in company private GitLab #####> requirements.txt
@echo. --extra-index-url https://__token__:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/MAGIC_NUMBER_HERE/packages/pypi/simple>> requirements.txt
@echo.>> requirements.txt
@echo. #ADD packages in company private GitLab HERE#>> requirements.txt
@echo.>> requirements.txt

poetry export -f requirements.txt --without-hashes >> requirements.txt

poetry version patch

poetry build
```

The key take away is `poetry version patch` which is simple. As you can see there are other things I do for every build, which do not always apply.

This is a simple and brittle scheme. It is all I needed.
It handles this case:
main -> child -> gchild.

But if it is more complicate it falls apart.
main -> child1 -> primitives, and
main -> child2 -> primitives

In this case primitives will get built twice, which at best is a waste of time. I think Python resolves this conflict by choosing the latest version, which should work.

A better approach is to have a single batch file that bumps all of the versions first, then builds all of the packages.